# ElementNotInteractableException - Python / selenium not duplicate

Tags: python, selenium

Having trouble .sendkeys  to the password text box  after it has been selected and i can see the cursor flashing waiting for some text input

This is the html

```
<div class="hm-Login ">
    <div class="hm-Login_UserNameWrapper ">
        <input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
        <div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Join</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ">
        <input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
        <input type="password" class="hm-Login_InputField Hidden ">
        <button tabindex="0" class="hm-Login_LoginBtn ">GO</button>
        <div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Lost Login?</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("xxxxx/chromedriver")

driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/HO/');
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='TopPromotionBetNow']").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']"))).click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name("hm-Login_InputField").click()                                          
#time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

#username
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("hm-Login_InputField")
elem.click()
elem.clear() 
elem.send_keys("xxxx")

#password
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']//input[@type='text']")
#elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
elem.clear() 
elem.click()

#attempt 1
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']//input[@type='text']"))).send_keys("xx")

#attempt 2
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
elem.send_keys("xxxxx!")
```

this is the error    **ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable**

any help is appreciated..
you can see my attempts at the bottom of the code...

Comment: not sure it's the issue here but "((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']//input[@type='text']")))" looks like too many parenthesis.  When you manually type in that field, is it showing the letters or is it a password type?

Comment: masked text\password type.    i took out the extra parenthesis, still no success

Comment: probably need to see more of the markup, but seems like something is switching the hidden class from one input to the other.  Hard to tell when that happens without seeing the script(s) on the page.  Try switching to //input[@type='password']

Comment: https://www.bet365.com.au is the website.

Comment: Try switching to //input[@type='password']     -- tried this...no success

Answer (score 0):

XPATH which you are using is getting an element with type=text. As soon as you click on this element class name gets "Hidden" appended, that's why when tried to enter a text in this element you get this error. Try below solution, First you click element with type=text and then clear and send keys to it's sibling element (type=password)

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']//input[@type='text']"))).click() 

# Now, Enter text into element with type=password attribute
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ')]//input[@type='password']"))).clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ']//input[@type='text']").send_keys("xxxxx!")
```

I tested this with Java and works fine. Sorry, I do not have Python currently but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

adding the following after specifying the driver seems to have done the trick and .send_keys("xxxx")  is now working

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

http://allselenium.info/wait-for-elements-python-selenium-webdriver/